# System.Global.CultureNotFoundException on some systems but not others

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

We had a request to add Haitian Creole resx files to our app from a customer.  We got the translations and I went to plug them in, but I immediately found there's scant browser support for **ht** as a language/locale code.  Chrome wouldn't let you enter it anywhere.  IE 11 let you enter it as a custom code.  Only Edge and Firefox offered it up.

But the perplexing part to me is that when I go to a debug system with those resx files plugged in, and I hit the site with a browser, I get a System.Global.CultureNotFoundException on the following line:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
```

But if I go to a different system with our release build that *doesn't* have the resx files, there's no error.  Obviously I don't get any Haitian Creole translations either, but that same like of code does not blow up when presented with ht.

I've executed the same powershell command to list the supported languages on both systems, and Haitian Creole is not on the list of either system.

```
[system.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures('AllCultures')
```

Is it some release mode build thing to quietly fall back to the system language when a browser presents an unrecognized code?  Near as I can tell the only differences between my test systems is release mode/no ht resx and debug mode/with ht resx.

I don't get why I'm not getting the same exception in both places...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the System.Global.CultureNotFoundException exception occurs when your app **has resx files for the locale code** but the system at wide doesn't recognize it.

Taking advantage of the IE 11 feature to enter any odd custom code you want, I added **xx-xx** and put it at the top of my list.  Of course, I don't have any resx files for xx-xx.

Requests to the site with an Accept-Language header leading with xx-xx do not throw a System.Global.CultureNotFoundException exception; it just quietly moves on to the next one down in the list.

The difference between my dev site and the other release builds was that my dev site had .ht.resx files in the build while the other qa sites did not

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole number of optimizations, the likely culprit here is the [Just-in-time compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation). If it detects anything it can classify as "dead code", it will not hesitate to cut it out.

When I tried to write code that forced a OOM Exception on a x32 System with the 2 GiB Limit, I ran into just that issue: If the problematic part was detected as "dead code", I literally could not force a OOM. A simple output order solved the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OOM_32_forced
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //each short is 2 byte big, Int32.MaxValue is 2^31.
            //So this will require a bit above 2^32 byte, or 2 GiB
            short[] Array = new short[Int32.MaxValue];

            /*need to actually access that array
            Otherwise JIT compiler and optimisations will just skip
            the array definition and creation */
            foreach (short value in Array)
                Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, the code is run the same in both conditions.  It was not optimized away as dead code.  The only thing that changes is the http header the browser users to say what locale the user prefers.

Comment: @user1664043: Okay, I have to guess widly. Maybe partner laganguages mater? Way back when Langauge Packs were not freely downloadable, you bought a specific langauge/region but got some Partner Langauges alongside. i.e., both Germany and Canada Language Packs included French. So with some langaug packs you might get "Haitian Creole". With others not. And it was mostly based on cultural proximity. Usually this seperate was removed with Windows 7+. But if your OS is old enough, it might still be in effect?

Comment: If there's some sort of "buy two, get one free" thing going on, wouldn't it still show up in the powershell [system.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures('AllCultures') command?  I mean, if it's available on the system, however it got there, wouldn't it be on the list?